# Get Value and close dialog with recycle view and custom adapter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

In my app I display a dialog with a custom adapter which have a list of items. I want to get the value of the item clicked on the dialog and close it.... I can only display it correctly.

Here is how I create  the dialog:

```
      AlertDialog dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).create();
      LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
      View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.banderes_dialog, null);

      myrecyclerview = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.recycleview);
      myrecyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager((dialogView.getContext())));
      RecyclerViewAdapterLanguages recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapterLanguages(dialogView.getContext(), lstLanguages);
      myrecyclerview.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(dialogView.getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
      myrecyclerview.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);


      dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
      dialogBuilder.show();
```

And here is my oncreateviewholder:

```
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v;
        v= LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.bandera_item,parent,false);
        final MyViewHolder vHolder = new MyViewHolder(v);

        vHolder.item_language.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Click on an item", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        return vHolder;
    }
```

How do I know the item clicked on my main activity. How can I close the dialog on my oncreateviewholder (after the toast)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have an interface and use it's callback on your activity to dismiss dialog

```
public interface OnItemClickListner {
    void OnItemClicked(View view, int position);
}
```

pass your listener to your adapter and then in item click

```
vHolder.item_language.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Click on an item", 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                onItemClickListner.OnItemClicked(v, position);
            }
        });
```

then implement interface in your activity
after this you have its override method where you can dismiss your dialog

```
@Override
public void OnItemClicked(View view, int position) {
    dialog.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vikas, seems that this is the right way to go. However I got an error. I defined a global OnItemClickListner mOnItemClickListner; variable, then call mOnItemClickListner.OnItemClicked(v, position); 
However I got this error : Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.test.sample.adapters.RecyclerViewAdapterLanguages$OnItemClickListner.OnItemClicked(android.view.View, int)' on a null object reference

Comment: It just because maybe you are not passing interface reference to your adapter. have to do like `private void setListener(OnItemClickListner mOnItemClickListner) { this. mOnItemClickListner = mOnItemClickListner }` in your adapter and set listener while initialize adapter in your actvity.

Comment: Hi Vikas, I think I made the part in the adapter (just copy your text on it), but I do not know how to initialize the listener in the activity....
Thanks for your help

Comment: do this `myrecyclerview.setListener(new OnItemClickListner() {
             public void OnItemClicked(View view, int position) {        
             dialog.dismiss();}                                                                                                        });`

Comment: Thanks for your kind words, happy to help you!!